# Pancake Glutton Finding the biggest value in an array

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    int temp[99];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> temp[i];
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 11; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 11; b++) {
            if (temp[a] > temp[b]) {
                t = temp[a];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int a = 1; a < 11; a++) {
        if (temp[a] = t) {
            cout << "Person " << temp[a] << " ate the most pancakes\n" ;
        }
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

So I'm doing this practice problem on cplusplus.com called pancake glutton.With this code I'm just trying to identify who ate the most pancakes but every time I finish the program I get a long amount of numbers and a repeat of the last forloop 5 times. What am I doing wrong ? Here it is.
"Pancake Glutton
Requires:
variables, data types, and numerical operators
basic input/output
logic (if statements, switch statements)
loops (for, while, do-while)
arrays

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
Once the data has been entered the program must analyse the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

★ Modify the program so that it also outputs which person ate the least number of pancakes for breakfast.

★★★★ Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.
i.e.

```
Person 4: ate 10 pancakes
Person 3: ate 7 pancakes
Person 8: ate 4 pancakes
...
Person 5: ate 0 pancakes"
```

Comment: it doesnt spam it 5 times but it still gives me an outragous number when i add the == intead of =.

Comment: `std::max_element` (and then `std::minmax_element`) may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several bugs.
1). Variable t was not initialized.
2). You entered only 10 elements. That means that valid indicies are 0 - 9. But then you try to access 11 elements instead of 10. So loops like this

```
for(int a = 0;a<11;a++)
```

are incorrect.

3) These loops have no any sense.

```
for(int a = 0;a<11;a++)
{
    for(int b = 0;b<11;b++)
    {
        if(temp[a]>temp[b])
        {
            t = temp[a];

        }
    }
}
```

4) Here you use the assignment operator instead of the comparison operatpr

```
   if (temp[a] = t)
```

5) You should include header `<cstdlib>` because you use function system declared in the header.

As i understand all what you need is to write code that finds the maximum value among elements of an array.

To find the index of the maximum element you can use the following code.

```
int theBiggest = 0;

for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
{
   if ( temp[theBiggest] < temp[i] ) theBiggest = i;
}

cout << "Person " << theBiggest << " ate the most pancakes equal to " << temp[theBiggest] << endl  ;
```

Comment: @sickist Waht do you try to do in these loops?

Comment: Check which input is the highest

Comment: put how would i add an input because from that all i see is it saying that 9 will always be the biggest number

Comment: that makes no sense person thebiggest at the most pancakes doesnt that mean that the most amount of pancakes eaten is the person number?

Comment: temp[theBiggest] what does this exacly mean?

Comment: Does it mena there is a varible in there called thebiggest?Can i get a detailed explination.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an assignment instead of an equality test (operator= instead of operator==):

```
if (temp[a] == t)
```

Comment: it doesnt spam it 5 times but it still gives me an outragous number